# Module dependent js on/off backend config

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I'm developing a module which depends on `jquery` and `colorboxjs`. And i'm doing this giving options on backend config to select yes/no for jquery/colorbox to embed or not individually. And now in the phtml file :

```
<?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('Mymodule_options/section_one/jquery_state')): ?>
    jQuery CDN Link || Link to skin/frontend/base/default/Mymodule/js/jquery.js
<?php endif; ?>
```

And i did similarly with colorboxjs. Is this approach ok for developing module or i have to follow some other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it through your module `xml`.

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem" ifconfig="Mymodule_options/section_one/jquery_state"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/my_module/my_module.js</name></action>
</reference>
```